# VS 2008 Pre Build Command line too long for command prompt

Tags: xslt, visual-studio-2008, command, prebuild

i have a problem with VS2008 Pre build command.

I need to compile a lot of XSLT style sheets and generate a common assembly, i use xsltc.exe but the command string is too long for command prompt.

I tried to use also a .bat file, i use the xsltc.exe command in the best way for save some character, like using "\c" instead of "\class", but the problem still remains.

Do you have any suggestion to solve this problem? please note that i can't install on my machine additional tools.

Thank You All!

Answer (score 0):

Can you post the full command you're trying to run?

If you are trying to feed the compiler with whole path names to the stylesheets, would it perhaps help to, in the batch file, cd to the directory containing your stylesheets and then run the following command?

```
c:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\bin\xsltc /out:MyAssembly stylesheet1.xsl stylesheet2.xsl stylesheet3.xsl [...]
```

i.e. for example:

```
cd c:\My\Stylesheets
c:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\bin\xsltc /out:MyAssembly stylesheet1.xsl stylesheet2.xsl stylesheet3.xsl ...
```

instead of:

```
xsltc /out:c:\My\Stylesheets\MyAssembly c:\My\Stylesheets\stylesheet1.xsl c:\My\Stylesheets\stylesheet2.xsl c:\My\Stylesheets\stylesheet3.xsl [...]
```

I have not worked with xsltc (and you haven't provided enough information) so please excuse any formal flaws.